# How to copy select data from one worksheet into another on trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I've written a script to collect data by global variables:

```
var row = sheet.getActiveSelection().getRowIndex();
var mfg = sheet.getRange("M" + row).getValue().toUpperCase()
var changeOrder = sheet.getRange("W" + row).getValue().toUpperCase()
var sku = sheet.getRange("H" + row).getValue()
var revision = sheet.getRange("AE" + row).getValue()
var productName = sheet.getRange("J" + row).getValue().toUpperCase()
var packSize = sheet.getRange("K" + row).getValue().toUpperCase()
var project = sheet.getRange("D" + row).getValue().toUpperCase()

var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Ai_j76HcGMnIdG1QNDgxQU1NWWVIQ2o2bkM5SjdtQ0E').getSheetByName('Tech Newsletter - Current');
var targetLastRow = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target
var targetNewRow = targetLastRow+1

var nlMfg = targetNewRow.getRange("C").setValue(mfg);
```

and I want to run a custom script, when the menu option is selected, it will take the global variables and add them in custom order (next available row) to a pre-defined worksheet or another google doc if possible.

The other worksheet is called "Newsletter" and 
Column A = Timestamp, Column B = User, Column C = mfg, Column D = changeOrder, Column E = sku, Column F = productName + packSize, Column G = project

I am able to write a function to get a text box, but this doesn't help. The research I've done only leads me to copying an entire range based on criteria. Not helping. I have the menu option already, but need a function to tell the document where to put the data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

See spreadsheetApp.openById(yourid).appendRow

Comment: Thank you Zig, I tried several different times, and I think this is the closest, but I am getting "SpreadsheetApp not defined" error?{function addNewsletter() {
    var spreadSheet = spreadsheetApp.openById('0Ai_j76HcGMnIdG1QNDgxQU1NWWVIQ2o2bkM5SjdtQ0E&usp=drive_web#gid=0');
    var destination = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Tech Newsletter - Current');
    destination.appendRow([mfg, sku + " REV" + revision, productName + packSize, project, portfolio])
  }

Comment: Also tried: 'var spreadSheet = spreadsheetApp.openById('0Ai_j76HcGMnIdG1QNDgxQU1NWWVIQ2o2bkM5SjdtQ0E&usp=drive_web#gid=0').getSheetByName('Tech Newsletter - Current').appendRow([mfg, sku + " REV" + revision, productName + packSize, project, portfolio])' Same error

Comment: oops, I didn't notice the & sign.

Comment: Okay, now I am getting somewhere... but I have an error "Cannot find function in getRange object 219" Where 219 is the next blank row. Here is the code   `  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Ai_j76HcGMnIdG1QNDgxQU1NWWVIQ2o2bkM5SjdtQ0E').getSheetByName('Tech Newsletter - Current');
  var targetLastRow = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target
  var targetNewRow = targetLastRow+1
  
  var nlMfg = targetNewRow.getRange("C").setValue(mfg);`

Comment: Please avoid writing code in comments, if you need to update your question with new information edit your post. Code in comment is really a pain to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0Ai_j76HcGMnIdFRUUFZIRTdsUmhXdjcxUmtmSlY3Mmc').getSheetByName('Newsletter Template');
  var targetLastRow = targetSS.getLastRow(); // Get # rows currently in target
  var targetNewRow = targetLastRow+1


 targetSS.getRange("A"+targetNewRow).setValue(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
 targetSS.getRange("B"+targetNewRow).setValue(username)
 targetSS.getRange("C"+targetNewRow).setValue(mfg);
 targetSS.getRange("D"+targetNewRow).setValue(changeOrder);
 targetSS.getRange("E"+targetNewRow).setValue(sku + " REV" + revision);
```